# How in terraform using google platform provider do I get instance information from a instance created with google_compute_region_instance_group?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I am creating a terraform file so I can setup some VMs in GCP to build my own Kubernetes platform (Yes google has their own engine but I want to use some custom items). I have been able to create the .tf file to create the whole stack just like the other setup in the Kubespray project. Something like what you do to terraform VMs on AWS.

The last part I need to automate is the creation of the host file for Ansible.

I create the Masters and Workers using a resource called `google_compute_region_instance_group` which places each instance in a different AZ with in GCP. Now I need to get the hostname and IP give to these instances.  The problem I have is that they are dynamically created recourses. So to pull this information out I use a data source to grab the info.

Here is what I have now.

```
data.google_compute_region_instance_group.data_masters.instances
[
  {
    "instance" = "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/appportablityphase2/zones/us-east1-c/instances/k8-masters-4r2f"
    "named_ports" = []
    "status" = "RUNNING"
  },
  {
    "instance" = "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/appportablityphase2/zones/us-east1-d/instances/k8-masters-qh64"
    "named_ports" = []
    "status" = "RUNNING"
  },
  {
    "instance" = "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/appportablityphase2/zones/us-east1-b/instances/k8-masters-w9c8"
    "named_ports" = []
    "status" = "RUNNING"
  },
]
```

As you can see the output is a mix of a list and maps.  I am able to get just the instance self url with this line.

```
lookup(data.google_compute_region_instance_group.data_masters.instances[0], "instance")

https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/appportablityphase2/zones/us-east1-c/instances/k8-masters-4r2f
```

Which then I can split and get the instance name.  This is the hard part that I can not figure out with Terraform.  In the above line I have to use `[0]` to call the instance information.  I then need to iterate through all of the instance which may be more then 3 or 3.

I can not find a way to do this with this data source type.  I have tried count.index but it only supported in a resource type not data source.  I have also tried splat syntax and it has not worked.

Comment: Is there a good reason you want to run Ansible against the instances when they come up rather than bake the config into an image?

Comment: I need a hosts file to run ansible.  Here is the link to the AWS set of terraform that i used.  I just trying to replicate this.
https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/kubespray/tree/master/contrib/terraform/aws

Comment: Yes, I was asking why not just bake the config into the image (potentially using Ansible) instead of trying to Ansible the instances after they are created?

Comment: Bake what config?  I have to run the ansible playbook to setup and install Kubernetes and other services.

Comment: All i need here is the name of the instance that where create.  Plain and simple.  Right now all i get is a URL.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think generating manually the inventory is the right approach although it is possible.

You could give a try to GCP Dynamic Inventory, which generates inventory from running instances based on their network tags.

For instance, instance A has tags foo, and instance B has tags foo and bar, the generated inventory will be:

```
[tag_foo]
A
B

[tag_bar]
B
```

Script is available at this address: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/contrib/inventory/gce.py

Configuration file here: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/contrib/inventory/gce.ini

And usage is `ansible-playbook -i gce.py site.yml`